# Helper- menu e submenu ativo (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!
Estou utilizando o helper menu para incluir `class active` nos menus do site.

Helper Menu:

```
<?php 
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    if(!function_exists('active_link'))
    {
        function menu_ativo($controller)
        {
        //Obtem Instância da classe CI
        $CI = get_instance();
        //Obtem classe ativa.
        $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
        return ($class == $controller) ? 'active' : '';
       }
    }
?>
```

E invoco esta função conforme abaixo

```
<li class="treeview <?php echo menu_ativo('conta'); ?>">
   <a href="#">
   <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
   <span><?php echo 'Financeiro'; ?></span>
   <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
   </a>
   <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li class="<?php echo menu_ativo('categoria'); ?>">
         <a href="<?php echo site_url('app/categoria'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Categoria</a>
      </li>
      <li class="<?php echo menu_ativo('conta'); ?>">
         <a href="<?php echo site_url('app/conta'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Conta</a>
      </li>
      <li class="<?php echo menu_ativo('encargo'); ?>">
         <a href="<?php echo site_url('app/encargo'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Encargo</a>
      </li>
      <li class="<?php echo menu_ativo('lancamento'); ?>">
         <a href="<?php echo site_url('app/lancamento'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Lançamento</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

O meu problema é basicamente em `<li class="treeview <?php echo " ???? " ;?>">`

Já que cada `<li>` dentro de `<ul>` pertence a um controller diferente, eu quero ativar qualquer sub-menu e manter o menu-principal ativo `<li>`.
Porem com o helper acima não esta funcionando, embora o submenu esteja herdando a `class active`, o menu principal está fechando.

Podem me orientar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
<li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=='categoria') echo "active"; ?>">
     <a href="<?php echo site_url('app/categoria'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Categoria</a>
</li>
```

Neste caso `URI->SEGMENT` na posição `(1)` representaria a URL: `app/categoria`. Ai você precisa testar, sendo echo `$this->uri->segment(1)` pra ver o que retorna, então saber em qual posição se encontra seu módulo.

Edit: Em caso de ser submenu, você pode fazer uma validação entre os módulos, `if($this->uri->segment(1)=='categoria' or $this->uri->segment(1)=='categoriaB' or $this->uri->segment(1)=='categoriaC') echo "active";`

Ou caso você não deseja fazer assim, coloque em cima de cada módulo, no construc:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('modulo_ativo', 'Financeiro');
```

Ai você então faz:

```
if($this->session->userdata('modulo_ativo')!=NULL && $this->session->userdata('modulo_ativo')=='Financeiro') echo "active";
```

Isto em se tratando do menu principal, não submenu.

Comment: Funcionou desta forma: `Edit: Em caso de ser submenu, você pode fazer uma validação entre os módulos, if($this->uri->segment(1)=='categoria' or $this->uri->segment(1)=='categoriaB' or $this->uri->segment(1)=='categoriaC') echo "active";`

Obrigado.